# Can rust return a recursively built solution?

Tags: recursion, rust, dynamic-programming

In dynamic programming problems solutions are built up from smaller pieces and returned to the caller. A super-simplified version of this is to build a list recursively based on a count. Rust lifetimes seem to make this more complicated. Is it possible to use rust to build the solution entirely inside one function or a set of functions and then return it, or do you always need to pass in a mutable result variable so that the variable holding the solution has a lifetime that is guaranteed to exist for the duration of the scope that will use it?

```js
//result is created inside and passed out
function list_build_recursive(count){
    if (count == 0) { return []; }
    if (count > 0) {
        let result = list_build_recursive(count-1);             
            result.push(count);
            return result;
                    
    }
}


console.log(list_build_recursive(5));
```

```
//is it possible for result to be created inside and passed out?
pub fn list_build_recursive(count: i32, result: &mut Vec<i32>){
    if count > 0 {
            list_build_recursive(count-1, result);
            result.push(count);
            return;
    }
}


fn main() {    
    let result = &mut vec![];
    list_build_recursive(5, result);
    println!("list is {:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: As falsetru's answer shows, the straight-forward equivalent works just fine, were you having issue with something in particular?

Comment: I was trying to memoize possible ways of summing a list of numbers with a memo object consisting of a current sum hash key pointing to a list of values that result in that sum.  I had trouble trying to return a result stored locally. Then I read that rust can't return a reference to a temporary value, so I was trying to pass in a reference to a mutable hashmap, which caused a compiler error when returning from the base case. falsetru has pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fn list_build_recursive(count: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    if count == 0 {
        vec![]
    } else {
        let mut result = list_build_recursive(count - 1);
        result.push(count);
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("list is {:?}", list_build_recursive(5));
}
```